# Why does a rate close to $1$ make a code less 'useful'?

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

I thought about asking this question on CS theory stack exchange, but it is not research level, and the closest SE is math. Please migrate this question if it's off topic.

I'm reading *Information theory, inference and learning algorithms*, by David J. MacKay, and I'm confused about the way he treats code rate. If I understand correctly, the rate of a code answers the question

> How many bits of information can we send through a lossy channel, if we encode the message in $N$ bits?

the answer is $K=RN$, and clearly $R\leq 1$. While discussing perfect error correcting codes, the book contains the following statement

> We will show in several ways that useful perfect [$t$-error correcting] codes do not exist (here, 'useful' means 'having large block length $N$, and rates close neither to $0$ nor to $1$')

Question: why is it bad for a code to have a rate close to $1$? It seems to me that the closer the rate is to $1$ the better, since that way we don't need many additional bits to encode a message. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the application.

> Codes with rate close to $1$ can only correct a handful of bit errors within a longish block. When the application in mind is forced to deal with more than, say one erroneous bit in hundred being wrong, we are forced to use a lower rate code to cope.

- However, we can use a code of rate $\approx 1$, if the channel is extremely good. As an extremal case consider reading of data from a disk (or a more modern variant). Hardly any bit errors will occur. We still want to make sure that the retrieved data is correct with high probability. For such a purpose [a simple CRC check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) suffices. By sacrificing 32 bits out of 4 billion, we are guaranteed to detect a situation where one or two bits were flipped, and other random patterns of errors fail to get caught with probability something like $10^{-9}$. Tagging a CRC can be viewed as using a code with rate $1-\epsilon$ for a relatively small value of $\epsilon\approx 32/4000000000$.
- But MacKay is chiefly discussing applications, where the system actually needs to correct channel errors. You see most channels produce so many errors that A) the codes with rate close to 1 simply cannot handle them, and OTOH B) the codes with rate close to 0 cannot transmit all the data reasonably fast. The realistic channel requires codes somewhere in between.
- To mention one application I am somewhat familiar with let us consider the transmission of a terrestrial digital TV signal, i.e. broadcast supposed to reach a vast majority of consumers. It is not cost efficient to build enough many [radio masts and towers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_masts_and_towers) to provide all the consumers a good enough channel such that, say less then ten bits out $64000$ would be in error. Because locating a single bit within $64000\approx 2^{16}$ requires 16 bits of information, we need roughly $16\cdot10=160$ redundant bits to correct those errors (BCH-codes will deliver this). Then we would have a code of rate $R=1-(160/64000)=0.9975$. But, for some receivers, more distant from the mast and/or behind a hill, may be 5-10 percent of the received bits will be in error while we allow only $10/64000$. No good.

Anyway, the game to be played is to design the system to cope with a foreseeable probability of a received bit being in error, and also be able to transmit data at a prescribed rate. We usually cannot guarantee transmission free of errors, but most applications don't need that. For example, when a Europe wide system for broadcasting a TV signal was being updated a bit over ten years ago (yours truly was there), the prescribed quality of service was that after the error-correcting-code has done its magic, the system should have a bit error probability at most $10^{-11}$. That may sound like asking a lot, but consider the following. The data stream consists of compressed video. A single errorneous bit will cause the decompression to fail (how severely depends on exactly where the error is), producing a small a black block on the TV screen. A typical HD-quality stream has 10 million bits per second. So if we allowed a bit error probability of $10^{-10}$, then there would be a black block on the screen every 1000 seconds, that is every fifteen minutes. It was decided that the consumers would not be happy with that.

IIRC the raw (=uncoded) bit error rate in such a brodcast channel was up to something like 5-15 percent for *some* receivers to be served (obviously not to those living close to the mast). So BCH-codes simply would not work. The so called LDPC-codes studied extensively by MacKay and others, however, do get the job done. This is because, unlike the algebraically more interesting BCH-codes, they are designed to take reliability information about individual received bits into account. A well designed receiver can recognize many of the errorneously received bits as unreliable (so called *soft errors*), and LDPC-codes take that into account without any penalty to the decoding complexity.

Comment: I could go on for a week or so. Many essential aspects are missing. May be I just stop :-)

Comment: Thanks @user438666. I will edit the answer, when I find more time. One story missing from my answer is that the rate of code and its ability to correct a percentage of errors are inversely related. The exact relation is not known, but there are bounds. The simplest of which is [the Singleton bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_bound), uselessly crude for binary codes. Only mentioning it because the WP-page contains links to more refined bounds.

Comment: ah, that makes it clearer. Is that the reason why the only two perfect error correcting codes that exist the rate of which doesn't go to $0$ with the block size only correct 1 (Hamming) or 3 (Golay) errors? Anyway, I think the phrasing is weird because from your answer I gather that perfect $t$-error correcting codes (with $t>3$) with rate close to one would be very useful, but they do not exist! From the phrasing it sounds like even if such a code existed, it would not be useful for any $t$